# Mongoose: How can I update a document using a variable in the callback?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am looping through a list of ids, finding the entry associated with that id, and I want to update a "score" value based on its current value. like so:

```
id_array= ['2l3k4jixc','2343xjl','l243xkj33',.......];
var K=5;
for (var i=0, i<id_array.length;i++){
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id_array[i], { $set: { value:update_variable }}, options, function(err,found_item){
    update_variable= ((K-found_item.score)^3)/2;
}
})
```

right now it is trying to use `$set: {score:update_variable}` before update_variable has been defined by the callback function. So I think it does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently there is no way to refer to another field value within any form of `update` statement in MongoDB in general, so you are generally stuck with "finding" the item and then issuing a separate `.save()` method:

```
Model.findById(id_array[i],function(err,found) {
    found.value = ((doc.score)^3)/2;
    found.save();
});
```

Additional callback in the save is optional ( advised ) to your purpose, but this is the only current way to set one field based on the value of another. So bulk updates are right out unless you are looping.

Comment: what would go in the callback for save?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Just the usual error and resulting document. See save in the documentation for more details. But it generally is a good idea to check whether an error resulted, I didn't above just for shorthand.

Comment: additionally, are you saying that I cannot use a variable in the update statement? So passing in {$set: {score:some_variable}} as an argument to the update is illegal/will cause an error?